# how to create PayPal pay buttons that pays multiple people

Tags: paypal

I want to create a set of buttons from a list of PayPal emails (sellers). And when the user clicks on the button he/she will be brought to a PayPal page to pay X amount of money to the seller *and* Y amount to one other person (me). Each button pays different amounts and different people. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Answer (score 0):

you can use single button to process payment to different people with different amount with

`Paypal Payment Standard`

here is the documentation for implementing

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/